# How to use nested_flatbuffer attribute in Flatbuffers correctly?

Tags: flatbuffers

I am reading the documentation and I have the schema that looks like this:

```
table OuterMessageType {
    inner: [ubyte] (nested_flatbuffer: "InnerMessageType");
}
```

Questions

1. I don't see any convenient accessor in my generated code. Is above syntax correct?
2. I have a bytes object for the inner message and I want to construct a OuterMessageType object. How do I do it?
3. How do I read the inner message as a flatbuffer type on the receiving end? What does the code for that look like?

Comment: What language are you using? The above syntax looks correct.

Comment: Rust is the language

Comment: You'd have a better chance of an answer if you open an issue on github